# Converting 'const char*' to 'LPCTSTR' for CreateDirectory

Tags: c++, c2664

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string FilePath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\whatever";
    CreateDirectory(FilePath, NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Error: error C2664: 'CreateDirectory' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'

1. How do I make this conversion?
2. The next step is to set today's date as a string or char and concatenate it with the filepath.  Will this change how I do step 1?
3. I am terrible at data types and conversions, is there a good explanation for 5 year olds out there?

Comment: I'd hate to break this to ya but C++ wasn't geared toward 5-year-olds. :(

Comment: And neither was API programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` is a class that holds `char`-based data.  To pass a `std::string` data to API functions, you have to use its `c_str()` method to get a `char*` pointer to the string's actual data.

`CreateDirectory()` takes a `TCHAR*` as input.  If `UNICODE` is defined, `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`, otherwise it maps to `char` instead.  If you need to stick with `std::string` but do not want to make your code `UNICODE`-aware, then use `CreateDirectoryA()` instead, eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::string FilePath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\whatever";
    CreateDirectoryA(FilePath.c_str(), NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

To make this code `TCHAR`-aware, you can do this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> FilePath = TEXT("C:\\Documents and Settings\\whatever");
    CreateDirectory(FilePath.c_str(), NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

However, Ansi-based OS versions are long dead, everything is Unicode nowadays.  `TCHAR` should not be used in new code anymore:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::wstring FilePath = L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\whatever";
    CreateDirectoryW(FilePath.c_str(), NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your last example works.  This leads to more questions.  What is a wstring?  What does the 'L' do?  Is CreateDirectoryW() another available method or a modification of an existing method?

Comment: `std::string` holds a `char`-based string. `std::wstring` holds a `wchar_t`-based string. Both are specializations of `std::basic_string`. `L` tells the compiler to store the literal in wide (`wchar_t`) format instead of narrow (`char`) format. Get yourself a good C++ book, it covers these things. As for `CreateDirectory()`, it is actually a precompiler macro that maps to `CreateDirectoryW()` if `UNICODE` is defined, otherwise it maps to `CreateDirectoryA()` instead. See the declaration in `winbase.h`. Most Win32 API functions that deal with string data have A/W versions available.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not building a Unicode executable, calling `c_str()` on the std::string will result in a `const char*` (aka non-Unicode LPCTSTR) that you can pass into `CreateDirectory`().

The code would look like this:

```
CreateDirectory(FilePath.c_str(), NULL):
```

Please note that this will result in a compile error if you're trying to build a Unicode executable.

If you have to append to `FilePath` I would recommend that you either continue to use `std::string` or use Microsoft's `CString` to do the string manipulation as that's less painful that doing it the C way and juggling raw char*. Personally I would use `std::string` unless you are already in an MFC application that uses CString.

Comment: This gives me the same error as before as well as: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: That means you are compiling for Unicode, which means `CreateDirectory()` is mapping to `CreateDirectoryW()`, which takes a `wchar_t*` as input. You cannot pass `std::string` data to `CreateDirectoryW()`, they are not compatible. You have to either use `std::wstring` instead, convert the `std::string` data to `wchar_t*` using `MultiByteToWideChar()`, or use `CreateDirectoryA()` instead.