# Convert a char * to inizialite an entity of type LPCTSTR for RegCreateKeyEx

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I know I am a Windows programming nob, so I am just learning.

I am writing a Command Line tool to work with some of the Registry Functions of the Windows API, but I need to convert a `char *` that comes from an `argv[]` array to initialize a `LPCTSTR` variable with the content but I don't know how to do that.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int count;
    DWORD Reserved = 0;
    LPTSTR lpClass = NULL;
    DWORD dwOptions = REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
    HKEY phkResult;
    DWORD lpdwDisposition;

    if (argv[1] == 0)
    {
        printf("There are no arguments, pleas type one at least. \n");
    }
    else if (std::string(argv[1]) == "-Clave")
    {
        if (std::string(argv[2]) == "HKCU")
        {
            printf("You are going to create a HKCU sub-key \n");
            HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;

            if (std::string(argv[3]) != "")
            {

                printf("You are going to create this sub-key: %s \n",argv[3]);

                //This is what I tried.

                LPCTSTR lpSubKey = TEXT("%s",argv[3]);

                RegCreateKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, Reserved, lpClass, dwOptions, samDesired, lpSecurityAttributes, &phkResult, &lpdwDisposition);

                if (lpdwDisposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
                {
                    printf("The registry key has been created. \n");
                }

            }
            else
                printf("No one");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No key has been specified \n");
        }

    }

    system("Pause");

}
```

Can you help me out?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting 'const char\*' to 'LPCTSTR' for CreateDirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370982/converting-const-char-to-lpctstr-for-createdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the MultiByteToWideChar function in Windows.h. Here's a nice and quick example:

```
const char * orig = "text1";
WCHAR buffer[6];
MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, orig, 5, buffer, 6 );
LPCWSTR text = buffer;
```

Whoops, that's for LPCWSTR. For LPCTSTR, just use :

```
LPCTSTR text = _T("text1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to explicitly call the Ansi versions of the Registry functions (`RegCreateKeyExA`, etc) and let Windows handle the conversions for you.  You are currently calling the Unicode versions of the functions (`RegCreateKeyExW`, etc), or you wouldn't be having conversion problems in the first place:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int count;
    HKEY hkResult;
    DWORD dwDisposition;

    if (argc < 1)
    {
        printf("There are no arguments, pleas type one at least. \n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-Clave") == 0)
    {
        if (argc < 3)
        {
            printf("There are not enough arguments typed in. \n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[2], "HKCU") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[3], "") != 0)
            {
                printf("You are going to create HKCU sub-key: %s \n", argv[3]);

                if (RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, argv[3], 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hkResult, &dwDisposition) == 0)
                {
                    if (dwDisposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
                    {
                        printf("The registry key has been created. \n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("The registry key already exists. \n");
                    }

                    RegCloseKey(hkResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Unable to create the registry key. \n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("No HKCU sub-key has been specified \n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No root key has been specified \n");
        }
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** If you want to be politically correct, most Win32 APIs that deal with text data actually deal with `TCHAR` (which is what you were attempting to use, but not successfully) so that they can be compiled for both Ansi and Unicode with a single codebase, eg:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv [])
{
    int count;
    HKEY hkResult;
    DWORD dwDisposition;

    if (argc < 1)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("There are no arguments, pleas type one at least. \n"));
    }
    else if (_tcscmp(argv[1], _T("-Clave")) == 0)
    {
        if (argc < 3)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("There are not enough arguments typed in. \n"));
        }
        else if (_tcsicmp(argv[2], _T("HKCU")) == 0)
        {
            if (_tcscmp(argv[3], _T("")) != 0)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("You are going to create HKCU sub-key: %s \n"), argv[3]);

                if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, argv[3], 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hkResult, &dwDisposition) == 0)
                {
                    if (dwDisposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
                    {
                        _tprintf(_T("The registry key has been created. \n"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _tprintf(_T("The registry key already exists. \n"));
                    }

                    RegCloseKey(hkResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("Unable to create the registry key. \n"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _tprintf(_T("No HKCU sub-key has been specified \n"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("No root key has been specified \n"));
        }
    }

    _tsystem(_T("Pause"));
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, since you are starting a new project, you are best off forgetting that Ansi even exists and just use Unicode for everything:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv [])
{
    int count;
    HKEY hkResult;
    DWORD dwDisposition;

    if (argc < 1)
    {
        wprintf(L"There are no arguments, pleas type one at least. \n");
    }
    else if (wcscmp(argv[1], L"-Clave") == 0)
    {
        if (argc < 3)
        {
            wprintf(L"There are not enough arguments typed in. \n");
        }
        else if (_wcsicmp(argv[2], L"HKCU") == 0)
        {
            if (wcscmp(argv[3], L"") != 0)
            {
                wprintf(L"You are going to create HKCU sub-key: %s \n", argv[3]);

                if (RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, argv[3], 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hkResult, &dwDisposition) == 0)
                {
                    if (dwDisposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"The registry key has been created. \n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wprintf(L"The registry key already exists. \n");
                    }

                    RegCloseKey(hkResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    wprintf(L"Unable to create the registry key. \n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"No HKCU sub-key has been specified \n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"No root key has been specified \n");
        }
    }

    _wsystem(L"Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I disagree. The simplest solution (and also the best) is to change the application to be Unicode and therefore the entry point signature to be `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])`. Then you can call the correct version of the API functions everywhere.

Comment: Switching an existing Ansi-based app to Unicode is not always a trivial task, depending on the data being used. The *simplest* solution is to keep the existing app using Ansi-specific APIs. The *next* solution is to migrate the code to use `TCHAR`-based APIs correctly (which the OP's original code is not) so that the app can remain Ansi when needed, but also introduce Unicode as needed. The *best* (not the *simplest*) solution in the long run is to drop Ansi altogether and switch to Unicode exclusively, if possible.

Comment: I suppose that's fair, changing an entire existing code base to be Unicode-compliant is not trivial. But from the way I read the question, he is just learning the Windows API for the first time and only has the code he's shown. It doesn't appear to be just a simple example of code used elsewhere in a more complex project.

Comment: In that regard, if starting a new project, then yes, by all means, start with Unicode from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to change `main` function declaration in this way :

> int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx) :

> You can also use _tmain, which is defined in TCHAR.h. _tmain resolves
>   to main unless _UNICODE is defined. In that case, _tmain resolves to
>   wmain.

Second parameter on [RegCreateKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724844.aspx) is on type[*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) `LPCTSTR`.
`lpSubKey` is declared by the same type and will be initialized properly when passed as an argument to the `RegCreateKeyEx` function .

Here is your source code compiled with Visual C++, and uses  *Multi-byte Character Set* (`_MBCS` macro is defined) :

```
// RegCreate.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// VC++ Compiler Options :
// cl /W3 /MT /O2 /D WIN32 /D _CONSOLE /D _MBCS /EHsc /TP RegCreate.cpp 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifndef _MBCS
    #define _MBCS
#endif

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    DWORD Reserved = 0;
    LPTSTR lpClass = NULL;
    DWORD dwOptions = REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
    HKEY phkResult;
    DWORD lpdwDisposition;
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "There are no arguments, pleas type one at least. " << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if((std::string(argv[1]) == "-Clave") && (std::string(argv[2]) == "HKCU") && (argc == 4))
    {

        std::cout << "You are going to create a HKCU sub-key " << std::endl;
        HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;

        if(std::string(argv[3]) != "")
        {
            std::cout << "You are going to create this sub-key: " << argv[3] << std::endl;
            //This is what I tried.
            LPCTSTR lpSubKey = argv[3];
            if(ERROR_SUCCESS != RegCreateKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, Reserved, lpClass, dwOptions, samDesired,
                                               lpSecurityAttributes, &phkResult, &lpdwDisposition))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if(lpdwDisposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
            {
                std::cout << "The registry key has been created. " << std::endl;
            }
            RegCloseKey(phkResult);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No one";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No key has been specified " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We can use the `TEXT` macro to define a string as being [Unicode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Unicode) or not, but in the above example this is not necessary .

If you use C++ I suggest you to change `printf` with `std::cout`, that works with ASCII characters .