# Cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCTSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, wav

I'm using this codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10138/Voice-Recording-Playing-back-using-simple-classes

```
void CFisterDlg::OnRecord() 
{
    CString string;
    m_RecButton.GetWindowText(string);
    if(string == "Record")
    {
        StartRecordingToFile();
        m_RecButton.SetWindowText("Stop");
    }
    else
    {
        StopRecordingToFile();
        m_RecButton.SetWindowText("Record");
    }
}
```

But I get this error in numerous places:

```
error C2664: 'void CWnd::SetWindowTextW(LPCTSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCTSTR'
```

I think it has something to do with me using the latest version of visual studio (2013).

Comment: @cybermonkey It's StackOverflow, not Grand Theft Auto: there's no steal.

Comment: @black There is, and it's widely frowned upon. See Meta.

Comment: @cybermonkey See [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370982/converting-const-char-to-lpctstr-for-createdirectory) question. Has the same solution that i posted, yet i received 3 downvotes. Got to love stackoverflow.

Comment: You have accepted a *very* damaging answer. Please consider changing it.

Comment: @Yakk Look at Remy's third paragraph/code block. That will clarify the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetWindowTextW()` takes a **character pointer to the string's data** where your string data consists of regular chars, but your function most likely expects a **unicode string**, so you cannot input string types directly. You need to use `L"thisismystring"`

Comment: Can you elaborate on its degree of wrongness? What specifically is incorrect?

Comment: @Yakk That's interesting because i've received this error multiple times in my work and have solved it using the solution i've provided. Maybe it is platform specific, mine being Wec7 RTOS. Nevertheless, i've provided a solution that i have used myself and have seen in other works. Likewise, you can reference [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) which goes into detail about the `SetWindowText` function and you can read about the specifics of the parameter. **I am using VS2008 and have received this error. It is not related to VS version**.

Comment: @Yakk What i meant to say is **a character pointer to the string's data.** I'' revise my grammar.

Comment: The second edit repaired the answer.  It still confuses `unicode* with *wide-character*, but that confusion is nearly mandated on windows.  -1 removed, +1 added.

Comment: The answer itself isn't wrong, the explanation however was (*and still is*).

Comment: @cybermonkey can you explain how it is still wrong?

Comment: @Javia1492 As Yakk says, your answer confuses a `unicode` with a wide character.

Answer (score 5):

There are two kinds of raw strings that MSVC2013 interacts with.  Raw `char` strings look like `"Hello"`.  `wchar_t` strings look like `L"World"`.

In addition, there is a setting for if your project is using `wchar_t` or `char` strings.  The macro `TCHAR` expands to either `char` or `wchar_t`, and the macro `_T("some text")` will expand to either `"some text"` or `L"some text"` depending on if your project is compiled to use `char` or `wchar_t`.

Almost every windows API taking a string has a macro wrapping it, mapping it to a `char` version or a `wchar_t` version.

The goal of all of this was to make it possible to write a single application, and have it wide-character aware or not.

The convention on windows is that narrow character `char` interfaces use a code-page based system, and wide character `wchar_t` interfaces use UTF-16 characters (the subset UCS-2 in OS's prior to W2K, and no system font in XP supports characters outside of UCS-2 if I read the wikipedia article right).

The end of all of this?  Your project has been somehow set to be using wide character strings.  This is a good thing, because narrow character built apps are unable to handle anything other than one codepage of characters.

So your narrow character constants are generating errors, as the APIs are now expecting wide character constants.

The easy fix is to wrap all of your `"raw strings"`s in `_T("raw string")` the `_T` macro.  When you use `char const*` or the like in your code, instead use `TCHAR const*`.

Include a system to do the same with `std::string` and `std::cout` and other `char` based `std` and other libraries, or when using those don't interact with the user and when talking to windows use the `A` terminated interfaces for `char` or `W` terminated interface functions for `wchar_t` based strings.

It is rare nowadays to ever "go back" to `char` based interfaces on windows, so one approach would be to do away with the macros and just interact with the `W` based interfaces directly.  Your strings all become `L"wide character"`, your `std` stuff is all `std::wstring` etc, and your character variables are all `wchar_t`.  This is probably not considered best practices.

Finally, note that both the `char` and `wchar_t` narrow and wide based interfaces can have more than one `char` or `wchar_t` per "character".  This wasn't true for a narrow window when all windows supported was single-`wchar_t` elements from UTF-16, and multi-`wchar_t` characters are relatively rare, so a lot of code fails to handle that possibility.

Comment: Your explanation is very informative, but your solution is no more different than mine. OP's question is very simple and focused, whereas your answer delves into the history and roots of microsoft's thinking. At the end of the day, both `_T()` and `L""` fix OP's solution, which is that he needs. Conversion of regular char to wchar_t. I dont see how this is any different that my "damaging" answer.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a `const char *` to an `LPCTSTR` type, add `L` before the `const char *`, as per se:

```
void CFisterDlg::OnRecord() 
{
    CString string;
    m_RecButton.GetWindowText(string);
    if(string == "Record")
    {
        StartRecordingToFile();
        m_RecButton.SetWindowText(L"Stop");
    }
    else
    {
        StopRecordingToFile();
        m_RecButton.SetWindowText(L"Record");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could inexplicably cast it with `_T`, like so:

```
void CFisterDlg::OnRecord() 
{
    CString string;
    m_RecButton.GetWindowText(string);
    if(string == "Record")
    {
        StartRecordingToFile();
        m_RecButton.SetWindowText(_T("Stop"));
    }
    else
    {
        StopRecordingToFile();
        m_RecButton.SetWindowText(_T("Record"));
    }
}
```

The `_T` macro comes from the 'tchar' library, therefore you'll need to `#include <tchar.h>` if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0):

`LPCTSTR` is a [cstring operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). I advocate you to do this in all your calls to `setWindowTExt`

```
setWindowText(_T("Record"))
```

`_T()` will call the implicit cast directly if the function is known from the compiler (Which is the case here). You could use `L""` aswell, thanks to @Mgetzfor point it out.

Comment: nobody is using windows 9x anymore, there is no need to use `_T()` any more, just use `L""`

Comment: @Mgetz In France there's still waaay more windows 9X that'd you think ! That's why i prefer to point out _T() anyway. But yeah, i should have putted both styles.

Comment: Using `_T` is good for compatibility, although it's surpassed by the newer `L`.

Comment: In which way its surpassed in terms of compatibility @cybermonkey ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mulit-byte character encoding in Project Settings instead of Unicode.
In case of VS2013, VS2015 you need to download and install the MBCS library for visual studio from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40770

Answer (score -4):

Try something like this:

```
char ch[5] = "test";
int num = MultiByteToWideChar(0,0,ch,-1,NULL,0); 
wchar_t *wide = new wchar_t[num];
MultiByteToWideChar(0,0,ch,-1,wide,num);
```